# Design xml menu in Android Studio not display objects (buttons, textview etc)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I get a strange problem. When I open design-menu for redacting xml file (Activity or Fragment) I dont see elements(buttons, textviews etc).

Picture:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a render problem, please click on the top right red exclamation mark to see the exact error.
For the time being, you can change the display theme to resolve the problem. Click on `AppTheme` in the top menu, and choose another theme (I would suggest `Material Light > Material.Light.DarkActionBar`
Please see the image below:

[image]